# BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately

Tags: python

I'm using a script from a friend to control Ableton 11 trough OSC messages (its in beta now), I got this error when sending fader data into the script:

data, addr = self._socket.recvfrom(65536)
BlockingIOError: [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately.

He is using a mac so I think it's a windows specific thing.

(I barely know python but I'm good at googling shit;) )

```
class OSCServer:
def __init__(self, local_addr=('127.0.0.1', OSC_LISTEN_PORT), remote_addr=('127.0.0.1', OSC_RESPONSE_PORT)):
    """
    Class that handles OSC server and client responsibilitiess

    Implemented because pythonosc's OSC server causes a beachball when handling
    incoming messages. To investigate, as it would be ultimately better not to have
    to roll our own.
    """
    self._local_addr = local_addr
    self._remote_addr = remote_addr

    self._socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self._socket.setblocking(0)
    self._socket.bind(self._local_addr)
    self._callbacks = {}

    self.logger = logging.getLogger("abletonosc")
    self.logger.info("Starting OSC server (local %s, remote %s)",
                     str(self._local_addr), str(self._remote_addr))

def add_handler(self, address: str, handler: Callable):
    self._callbacks[address] = handler

def clear_handlers(self):
    self._callbacks = {}

def send(self, address: str, params: Tuple[Any] = ()) -> None:
    """
    Send an OSC message.

    Args:
        address: The OSC address (e.g. /frequency)
        params: A tuple of zero or more OSC params
    """
    msg_builder = OscMessageBuilder(address)
    for param in params:
        msg_builder.add_arg(param)

    try:
        msg = msg_builder.build()
        self._socket.sendto(msg.dgram, self._remote_addr)
    except BuildError:
        self.logger.info("AbletonOSC: OSC build error: %s" % (traceback.format_exc()))

def process(self) -> None:
    """
    Synchronously process all data queued on the OSC socket.
    """
    try:
        while True:
            data, addr = self._socket.recvfrom(65536)
            try:
                message = OscMessage(data)

                if message.address in self._callbacks:
                    callback = self._callbacks[message.address]
                    rv = callback(message.params)

                    if rv is not None:
                        self.send(message.address, rv)
                else:
                    self.logger.info("AbletonOSC: Unknown OSC address: %s" % message.address)
            except ParseError:
                self.logger.info("AbletonOSC: OSC parse error: %s" % (traceback.format_exc()))

    except socket.error as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EAGAIN:
            return
        else:
            self.logger.info("AbletonOSC: Socket error: %s" % (traceback.format_exc()))

    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.info("AbletonOSC: Error handling message: %s" % (traceback.format_exc()))

def shutdown(self) -> None:
    """
    Shutdown the server network sockets.
    """
    self._socket.close()
```

Comment: A quick read shows this as single socket/single threaded.  The socket should be blocking, or that while loop is going to spin the CPU badly since it won't block (or it'll throw an exception).  I'd try just removing setblocking line.

Comment: Didn't work, ableton started crashing